# Copy value of metakey in user meta table in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, usermetadata

I would like to copy the value of the billing_company meta key (text type) from the wp_usermeta table to another metakey that is empty in the same table. My new metakey is called cuit (text type). I want to do this with all 2000 users and child.
What is the best way to do this? I migrated a db and I need to update this data.
Thank you!

Comment: Hi, do you have some code you have tried to do this?

Comment: Hello, not yet. Maybe someone had already implemented something like this already and could guide me, thanks!